# AsyncTask: how to communicate with another class with onProgressUpdate

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have set up an `AsyncTask`.

In `doInBackground()`, the only job is to call a method from another class. That method was copied from an old Java Applet, so while executing, it would print out progress every 10% onto the screen directly until finish. As this is not advisable in Android, I use `AsyncTask` to run it.

My question is, how to capture the Integer progressPercent spit out from that method in `doInBackground()`, and pass onto `onProgressUpdate()` to update the UI? How should I modify the original method to cope with the `AsyncTask` structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the `AsyncTask` class should be on the form

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<Object, Long, Object> 
// or 
class Task extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Object>
```

then edit the part that prints out progress every 10% inside the Task to

```
publishProgress(/*your progress here*/);
```

and finally your `onProgressUpdate` and its parameter depends on the object that you choose in the class definition

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
    long progress = values[0];
    // update UI here
}
// if you choose object Integer
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    int progress = values[0];
    // update UI here
}
```

BTW: You can use a loop to show the progress many times instead of just once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) for that, because `doInBackground()` will be called only once, so you cannot display the progress with that. You can update a progress bar for example with the handler in every 10% or even more often.